# Mysql selecting rows

Tags: mysql, select

I have a database scheme with a table like this:

```
id --- username --- sex
1         A          1
2         D          2
3         F          1
4         G          2
5         H          1
6         x          1
7         r          1
```

I want to select only 2 males and lets say 4 females, male is 1 and female is 2. How would we achieve that in one mysql  query and if I have more var's to select by ?

Comment: This must be homework.  Have you tried a query yet?

Comment: what's a query?

Comment: Yes i tried with join and trust me this not close to a home work ,, im making algorithm to show more females users than male if the current user is male

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(select * from your_table where sex = 1 limit 2)
union all
(select * from your_table where sex = 2 limit 4)
```